# How to delete custom list in Excel by C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am trying to delete a list in Excel custom list by C# language. But my program can't delete the list I want. I don't know what's problem with my program. It's don't notice any error.
I hope someone can help me to fix it.
Thank you so much.[image]

```
Object customListContents;
for (int i = 5; i <= excelApp.Application.CustomListCount; i++)
    {
        customListContents = excelApp.Application.GetCustomListContents(i);
        foreach (string item in (dynamic)(customListContents))           
                if (item == "China" || item == "Taiwan")                               
                    {
                        excelApp.Application.DeleteCustomList(i);
                         break; 
                    }                       
    }
```

Comment: What's the office version?

Comment: This is office 2016

Comment: anyone can help me?

Comment: Sorry, got a bit busy. Remind me please in ~10 hours. By that time I'll get home and install office 2016

Comment: Thank you so much. I am looking forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that all you need is this:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.DeleteCustomList(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.GetCustomListNum(new string[] { "China", "Taiwan" }));
```

Here is the same, a bit simpler but also longer:

```
// get an application object
Excel.Application xlApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;

// assign the list you want to remove to an array
string[] myList = new string[] { "China", "Taiwan" };

// get the number of your list from Excel application
int listNum = xlApp.GetCustomListNum(myList);

// delete the list by its number - it's the only way to delete 
// a custom list that I've found
xlApp.DeleteCustomList(listNum);
```